# how to get most variable rows from pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, dataframe

what is an efficient way to get the most variable rows from a (numeric) pandas DataFrame? by most variable rows, I mean the rows that are most variable with respect to column values - rows with the highest standard deviation, but since each row might be on a different scale, can't just take the largest absolute standard deviation of each row across column. One way to define this is to compute the absolute coefficient of variation:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randn(10), "b": np.random.randn(10), "c": np.random.randn(10)})
new_df = df.std(axis=1).div(df.mean(axis=1)).abs()
var_df = df[new_df.max(axis=1) > np.percentile(new_df.max(axis=1),80)]
```

is there a better more concise/efficient way to do this in pandas/numpy?

Comment: What do you mean by "the most variable rows"? Do you mean the rows with the most variability, for some metric of how much they vary? Do you mean you want to get most of the rows?

Comment: the rows that are most variable with respect to column values - i.e. have the highest standard deviation, but since each row might be on a different scale, i can't just take the largest std